# Bolding a specifc variable in PHP throughout a page

Tags: php

```
<?php
# session

session_start();

# check that session is set and is valid

if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
   { header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
<body>
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="keywordhead">
    <div align="center"><img src="Images/keyword_title.png" width="243" height="56" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
  <p>
    <?php

      $kword = $_POST["kword"];

      function boldText($text, $kword) {
    return str_replace($kword, "<strong>$kword</strong>", $text);
}
      $testin1 = substr($kword,0,1);
if($testin1 == "") {
print "<strong>No Keyword or a Keyphrase Entered, Please return to the '<a href='keyword_search.php'>Keyword Search Page</a>'</strong>";
}
else {
   // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
 mysql_real_escape_string($kword); 
 $data = mysql_query("select company_name, section_name, question, answer from company, rfp, section, question_keywords
where company.company_id = rfp.company_id
and rfp.rfp_id = question_keywords.rfp_id
and question_keywords.section_id = section.section_id
and keywords like '%$kword%';") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

  echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=10>";
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
<td><b>Company Name</b></td><td><b>Section</b></td><td><b>Question</b></td><td><b>Answer</b></td>" ; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td width = 130px>".boldText($info['company_name'], $kword) . "</td> ";
 echo "<td width = 60px>".boldText($info['section_name'], $kword) . " </td>"; 
 echo "<td width = 300px>".boldText($info['question'], $kword) . " </td>";
 echo "<td width = 600px>".boldText($info['answer'], $kword) . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 echo "</table>"; 
 ?>

  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><a href="logout.php"><br />
  Logout</a> | <a href="index.php">Index</a>  |  <a href="keyword_search.php">Back</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am relatively new to PHP, and i was curious as to whether a certain function is possible. I have a keyword Search and the code for the results page is above. I would like to bold wherever the $kword variable appears on the page. is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `str_replace($keyword, '<b>'.$keyword.'<b>', $targetString);` the dirtiest but fast solution.

Comment: And for your projects stop using `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO or mysqli_ instead

Comment: This code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack!  Use PDO and escape your variables!

Comment: Please note that you should stop script execution using `exit` after the `header()` function. The input values are currently not quoted in both directions - database and web client, see `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities()` and at least `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to do so, and call it prior to echo'ing the variables.

Instead of: `$info['question']` use `boldText($info['question'], $kword)`

```
function boldText($text, $keyword) {
    return str_ireplace($keyword, "<strong>$keyword</strong>", $text);
}
```

As a side note, don't forget to escape `$kword` with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before using it in a SQL query, or even better, consider using [MySQLi or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) since mysql extension is strongly discouraged

Comment: i have inserted the function, and there are no 'errors', but wherever $kword appear it isnt in bold?

Comment: @user1662306 Can you inspect the HTML and see if occurrences `$kword` are wrapped in `<strong>` tags?

Comment: i will edit the original question, could you make a recommendation then?

Comment: @user1662306 You're using `mysql_real_escape_wrong()`. It *returns* the escaped string, I included a link in my post, please take the time to read it. I've tested the function and it works perfectly fine. So I will ask my question again: *Can you inspect the HTML and see if occurrences $kword are wrapped in <strong> tags?*

Comment: the html doesnt have any <strong> wrapped $kwords

Comment: @user1662306 Do `$kword` and the word in the text have the same case? (ex: both lowercase?). `str_replace` is case sensitve, that could be the issue.

Comment: yes it is working but case sensitive, is there any way the case sensitivity can be avoided?

Comment: @user1662306 Yes. Use `str_ireplace` instead (which I never existed until today). I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this in each of your Print statements?

```
str_replace($kword, "<b>$kword</b>", $info[...])
```

(or CSS e.g. 
    <span style='font-weight:bold'>...</span>
if you prefer).